# Не могу добавить DataSource в С#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Привет. Не могу добавить DataSource в С# так как у меня нету этой кнопки.
 Пользуюсь Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: хмм, у меня тоже)
вангую: DataSour**с**e это не кнопка, а класс описывающий используемую структуру данных.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Скачайте инсталлятор Visual Studio 2017 с официального сайта Microsoft или запустите уже имеющийся. В открывшемся окне инсталлятора найдите свою установленную версию Visual Studio (которая установлена на вашем компьютере) и нажмите кнопку <kbd>Modify</kbd>, она может скрываться под кнопкий <kbd>More</kbd> открывающей выпадающий список.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, жмете кнопку модифицировать и переходите на вкладку окна <kbd>Individual Components</kbd>, там находите раздел <kbd>Cloud, database, and server</kbd> и пункты, связанные с `Data sources`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый `Data sources and service references` включает в себя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй `Data sources for SQL Server support` включает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отметьте галочками нужные вам компоненты, затем нажмите кнопку внижу окна <kbd>Modify</kbd>, ожидайте, пока установщик применит изменения, доставит компоненты, дождитесь завершения установки, перезагрузите компьютер и ищите недостающие компоненты в VS. Перед запуском инсталлятора, закройте все запущенные экземпляры Visual Studio и запускайте интсаллятор под администратором. Думаю, что это должно вам помочь решить ваш вопрос.

А вообще, возможно вы немного не об этом, есть еще идея такая, открыть VisualStudio в панели выбрать <kbd>View</kbd> далее перейти на пункт <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> там выбрать <kbd>DataSource</kbd> - появится вкладка источников данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А там уже кнопка добавления нового `DataSourсe`. Либо просто нажать на клавиатуре комбинацию клавиш <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> для отображения она источников данных.